# Duplicate legends in overlayed density plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to generate density plot with two overlaid distributions using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2).  My data looks like:

```
diag_elements <- data.frame(x = c(diag(Am.dent), diag(Am.flint)), 
                            group=rep(c("Dent", "Flint"), c(length(diag(Am.dent)), length(diag(Am.flint)))))
```

And my call to `ggplot` is:

```
ggplot(diag_elements) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x, colour=group, fill=group), alpha=0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Diagonal elements of the matrix", y = "Density", fill = "Heterotic Group") + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.85, .75))
```

However, instead of simply renaming the [legend](/questions/tagged/legend) with the more complete name specified in `fill`,  this generates a second `legend`:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting this same graph, but without the improperly formatted legend?

Thanks!

Comment: Try giving the same label to both elements - i.e. setting `colour = "Heterotic Group"` in `labs`

Answer (score 1):

The other option is guides which allows specific removal of certain legneds. You simply add to your ggplot 
`+guides(color=FALSE)`